# Here map Custom Style

Tags: javascript, angular, here-api

How can i Style HERE MAP's i.e

1. Hide Labels
2. Change color of Water e.g. oceans, rivers
3. Change color of Freeways and highways
4. Change color of Arterial s e.g. avenues, boulevards
5. Change Color of Parks, shopping centers, and airports
6. Change color of Other land then above mentioned points (2-5)

```js
    
/**
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToLocation(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:33.715617, lng:-117.794412});
  map.setZoom(10);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true,
  useHTTPS: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map);

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)

var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
moveMapToLocation(map);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, show your work.

Comment: Hi Soviut, thank you for your quick response. so far i have initialize map with a marker https://jsfiddle.net/4Lo2kxec/

Comment: Please update your question to include a working snippet rather than linking to offsite resources.

Comment: Hi Soviut, please check included snippet, i found below example where we can customize map tile which works for my requirement as well if we can modify code to Hide Labels , change color of water, freeways, parks, lands.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/example-custom-map-style.html

Comment: That definitely makes it clearer what Here Maps is, but where is your attempt at styling it? StackOverflow isn't an advice forum, we can help you fix your existing code, but we need to see what you've tried in order to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   
function moveMapToLocation(map){
 // map.setCenter({lat:33.715617, lng:-117.794412});
  //map.setZoom(10);
var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
      type: 'base'
    });
  var parameters = {};
  var tileLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'basetile',
      'normal.night',
      512,
      'png8',
      parameters
    );
  map.setBaseLayer(tileLayer)
}

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true,
  useHTTPS: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
defaultLayers.normal.map,{
 center: {lat:33.716514, lng:-117.794165},     
 zoom: 11
});
moveMapToLocation(map,platform);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />

</body>
</html>
```

```js
    
/**
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToLocation(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:33.715617, lng:-117.794412});
  map.setZoom(10);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true,
  useHTTPS: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map);

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)

var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
moveMapToLocation(map);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On tileLayer we can pass pre-defined options to hide labels and to render different map layers.